# How do I insert an empty row in a table with an auto-Increment primary key?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net, primary-key, auto-increment

I just want to grab the primary using the `SqlTransaction` method.

This is what I have so far:

```
using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    // insert IT Requirements
    string strITStaff = "INSERT INTO ITReq";
    strITStaff += "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    SqlCommand cmdITStaff = new SqlCommand(strITStaff, connection, transaction);
    ddlITSupport.SelectedValue.ToString());

    int ITStaffReq = Convert.ToInt32(cmdITStaff.ExecuteScalar());

    // update lanGaymen
    string strUpdatePhaseSix = "UPDATE lanGaymen SET ";
    strUpdatePhaseSix += "itReqID = @updateITReq ";
    strUpdatePhaseSix += "WHERE seasonID = @compareSeason";

    SqlCommand cmdUpdatePhaseSix = new SqlCommand(strUpdatePhaseSix, connection, transaction);
    cmdUpdatePhaseSix.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updateITReq", ITStaffReq);
}
```

Comment: So what doesn't work for you in the code you provided?

Comment: btw `strITStaff` will be `INSERT INTO ITReqSELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` what will cause a query parsing error. You may want to add a space. And don't construct a sql query this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to insert the default values including the "auto-increment" value, you need to use `DEFAULT VALUES` in your `INSERT`. Also, you need to have at least a `;` between your `INSERT` and your `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (your current code doesn't have a space nor a semicolon between the two statements):

```
string strITStaff = "INSERT INTO ITReq DEFAULT VALUES;  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```

This will insert all default values into the `ITReq` table, and then select the newly inserted `IDENTITY` from that table.